# Clustering many sentence using weka lib in java

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, weka

I have 5 files text.
I merge these files into 1 file. That file contain about 60 sentences.
I want to clustering that file to 5 cluster.
I am using weka to clustering.

```
public static void doClustering(String pathSentences, int numberCluster) throws IOException {

    Helper.deleteAllFileInFolder("results");

    //so cum bang so cau trong file / so cau trung binh trong 1 file
    HashMap<Integer, String> sentences = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> clustering = new HashMap<>();
    try {
        StringToWordVector filter = new StringToWordVector();
        SimpleKMeans kmeans = new SimpleKMeans();
        FastVector atts = new FastVector(5);
        atts.addElement(new Attribute("text", (FastVector) null));
        Instances docs = new Instances("text_files", atts, 0);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(pathSentences));
        int count = 0;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String content = sc.nextLine();
            double[] newInst = new double[1];
            newInst[0] = (double) docs.attribute(0).addStringValue(content);
            docs.add(new SparseInstance(1.0, newInst));
            sentences.put(sentences.size(), content);
            clustering.put(clustering.size(), -1);
        }
        NGramTokenizer tokenizer = new NGramTokenizer();
        tokenizer.setNGramMinSize(10);
        tokenizer.setNGramMaxSize(10);
        tokenizer.setDelimiters("\\W");
        filter.setTokenizer(tokenizer);
        filter.setInputFormat(docs);
        filter.setLowerCaseTokens(true);
        filter.setWordsToKeep(1);
        Instances filteredData = Filter.useFilter(docs, filter);
        kmeans.setPreserveInstancesOrder(true);
        kmeans.setNumClusters(numberCluster);
        kmeans.buildClusterer(filteredData);
        int[] assignments = kmeans.getAssignments();

        int i = 0;
        for (int clusterNum : assignments) {
            clustering.put(i, clusterNum);
            i++;
        }
        PrintWriter[] pw = new PrintWriter[numberCluster];
        for (int j = 0; j < numberCluster; j++) {
            pw[j] = new PrintWriter(new File("results/result" + j + ".txt"));
        }
        sentences.entrySet().stream().forEach((entry) -> {
            Integer key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            Integer cluster = clustering.get(key);
            pw[cluster].println(value);
        });
        for (int j = 0; j < numberCluster; j++) {
            pw[j].close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error K means " + e);
    }
}
```

When I change the order of the input file, the clustering results also vary.
Can you help me fix it. Thanks you so much.

Comment: why are you using 10-grams? I think this will make your clustering even harder.

Answer (score 1):

k-means is a randomized algorithm.

It picks some instances as initial seeds, then searches for a local optimum.

So of course it will produce different results!

If they vary a lot, this indicates it did not work well. If your data is good for k-means, then most runs will produce very similar results (except for permutation of labels).